# how to initialise and assign vlaue element by element to array dynamically

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I want to assign values to a dynamic array element by element in C++.
I use the code below to assign values

```
int *missedlst;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
missedlst = new int;
missedlst[i] = i;
}
```

If I print the values, only the last one is correctly shown. The remaining values are not: the program shows some garbage value.
Please help me in assigning the values element by element in a loop.

Comment: But there is no dynamic array in your code. I think you first need to figure out a) what a dynamic array is and b) how to make one.

Comment: Whenever you think "dynamic array" you should always next think [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: u got this down for ur writing quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code is doing exactly what you tell it to

```
int *missedlst;          // New pointer
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){   // Loop 10 times
    missedlst = new int; // Change what the pointer points to
    missedlst[i] = i;    // This makes no sense, you don't have an array
}
```

What you want is to create a new integer array, and then assign the values.

```
int size = 10;                   // A size that is easily changed.
int* missedList = new int[size]; // New array of size size
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){   // loop size times
    missedList[i] = i;           // Assign the values
}

// Do stuff with your missedList

// Delete the object.
delete[] missedList;
```

Comment: Actually what my scenario is, i dont want to give fixed size for array. its size should increase whenever i want to add new data into that array.

Comment: @NaveenKumar, then as already mentioned, you want a `vector`.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code, you allocate ten different "arrays", and each time only a single `int`, but you write to the i'th element of this one-element array, somewhere else leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (except when `i` is zero).

To make your *current* code work, you need to rewrite is as e.g.

```
int* missedLst = new int[10];  // Create an array of ten integers
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    missedLst[i] = i;  // Set the i'th element to the value of i
```

However, I recommend you use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, and then you have *three* ways to declare and initialize the vector:

1. Basically the same as you do now:

   ```
   std::vector<int> missedLst(10);  // Declare a vector of ten integers
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
       missedLst[i] = i;  // Set the i'th element to the value of i
   ```
2. Create each element dynamically:

   ```
   std::vector<int> missedLst;  // Declare a vector of integers, size zero
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
       missedLst.push_back(i);  // Add the value of i at the end
   ```
3. Initialize the vector with the [standard algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) function [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota):

   ```
   std::vector<int> missedLst(10);  // Declare a vector of ten integers
   std::iota(std::begin(missedLst), std::end(missedLst), 0);
   ```